# Multiple distinct count for ActiveRecord resource

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to count records by unique pair of attributes `attribute1` `attribute2`.

So for table `foo`

```
-----------------------------
id | attribute1 | attribute2 |
-----------------------------
1  | x          | y          |
2  | x          | y          |
3  | x          | y1         |
4  | x1         | y1         |
```

I'd like to get count = 3, so counted records: `([x,y], [x,y1], [x1,y1])`.
How to write this query with ActiveRecord ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a concise way to do it :

```
Foo.distinct.count("CONCAT(attribute1,attribute2)")
```